# Port OpenGL code from windows to Mac return version '150' is not supported

Tags: macos, opengl

I try to port my Angel's book's windows code to Mac and got GLSL version 150 not support error, which I am sure that my computer do support, i changed glGenVertexArrays() to glGenVertexArraysAPPLE()

I don't know why it return error like that?

```
 void init(){
    glGenBuffers( 3, buffers );
    //Vertex buffer for the vertex coordinates
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[cube_vertices] );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    //Elements buffer for the pointers
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[cube_indeces] );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[wire_indeces] );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices_wire), indices_wire, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(2, VAO);



    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader programs
    program[0] = InitShader( "vshader30_TwoCubes_FullPipe.glsl", "fshader30_TwoCubes.glsl" );
    program[1] = InitShader( "vshader30_TwoCubes_FullPipe.glsl", "fshader6_2.glsl" );
    program[2] = InitShader( "vshader6_2.glsl", "fshader6_2.glsl" );




    //VAO[0] the Cube
    glUseProgram( program[0] );
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[cube_vertices] );
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[cube_indeces]);
    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( program[0], "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
    //done with this packet
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);

    //VAO[1] the wireframe
    glUseProgram(program[1]);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(VAO[1]);
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[cube_vertices] );
    GLuint vPosition_Wire = glGetAttribLocation( program[1], "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition_Wire );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition_Wire, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[wire_indeces]);
    //done with this packet
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(0);

    //glUseProgram(0);

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glClearDepth( 1.0 );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
}

void display( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );



    //Make sure you start with the Default Coordinate Systems
    projmat=mat4(1.0);
    modelviewStackTop = mat4(1.0);
    mat4 modelviewStackBottom =  modelviewStackTop;
    //Set up the camera optics
    projmat = projmat*Perspective(30,1.0,0.1,20.0);

    //Position and orient the camera
    modelviewStackTop = modelviewStackTop*LookAt(eye, eye-n, v);
    modelviewStackTop = modelviewStackTop*Translate(0.15, 0.15, -2.5);

    modelviewStackBottom =  modelviewStackTop; //mvstack.push

    //Render wireframe
    glUseProgram(program[1]);
    proj_loc       = glGetUniformLocation(program[1], "projection");
    model_view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program[1], "modelview");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, projmat);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_view_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, modelviewStackTop);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(VAO[1]);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    modelviewStackTop = modelviewStackBottom; //mvstack.pop

    modelviewStackBottom =  modelviewStackTop; //mvstack.push

    //Render surface mesh
    glUseProgram(program[0]);
    color_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program[0], "color");
    proj_loc       = glGetUniformLocation(program[0], "projection");
    model_view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program[0], "modelview");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, projmat);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_view_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, modelviewStackTop);
    glUniform4fv(color_loc, 1, green_transparent);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(1.0, 1.0);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(VAO[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    modelviewStackTop = modelviewStackBottom; //mvstack.pop

    //The glut cone
    modelviewStackTop = modelviewStackTop*Translate(1.0, -1.0, -3.0);
    glUseProgram(program[2]);
    proj_loc       = glGetUniformLocation(program[1], "projection");
    model_view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program[1], "modelview");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, projmat);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_view_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, modelviewStackTop);
    glutSolidCone(0.5, 3.0, 2, 3);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: If you have to use the original APPLE VAO extension, then you do not have a GL3 context. What version of OS X are you using? 10.7+ supports OpenGL 2.1 (legacy) and OpenGL 3.2+ ***core***. Prior to 10.7, you are limited to 2.1. If you *do* have a **core** context, then all you need to do is `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>` and `glGenVertexArrays (...)`, etc. will be defined and you will not have to use APPLE's extension.

Answer (score 2):

OSX tops out at OpenGL 2.1 (`#version 120`) for non-Core contexts.

Make sure you use `#version 150 core` and request a Core context from GLUT.